# Kinematics, why must the final velocity be 50km/hr?

Tags: kinematics

but I am reading a paper on optimization which involves physics.

http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2011/04/2997.pdf

In page 17 (pg 16 bottom where it starts), just before the end of the first paragraph in the top it says

> Similarly to the
>   previous subsection, the final velocity Vf is fixed but in this case it has to be
>   equal to 50 km/h.

Why is that? Acceleration is not discussed in this paper. Is it because the final position is 100m that forces it to be 50km/hr?

Comment: Why down vote? You don't need to really read the beginnings of the paper, it won't offer much insight.

Comment: I can only guess, but one reason people might be downvoting is that your question is not self-contained. A reader has to click on the link to understand what you're asking, and we don't like questions of that nature here. If you were to edit your question to provide some context, so that people wouldn't have to click on the link to understand it, that might improve the response.

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): Echoing @David Z's comment: It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could try to make the question formulation self-contained, so one doesn't have to open the link to understand the question.

Comment: To be fair it would be a great deal of work to put all the details in the question as it would require reproducing large parts of the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See page 3 where $\Omega(t)$ is defined by:

$$ \frac{dpos(t)}{dt} = \frac{\Omega(t) r}{K_r} $$

so the linear velocity of the vehicle in km/h is given by:

$$ V(t) = \frac{3.6 r}{K_r} \Omega(t) \tag{1} $$

At the bottom of page 16 the constraint is introduced:

$$ \Omega(t) \le \frac{K_r}{3.6 r} 50 $$

Comparing this with equation (1) shows that the number $50$ is the maximum value the velocity can take i.e. the final velocity $V_f = 50$ km/h.

Comment: But maximum does not necessarily mean it will be attained. I thought of this as well, but it wrong.

Comment: What I mean is that despite compactness of the time interval (and EVT), I don't necessary have a $t_f$ that achieves the maximum.

Comment: It can be achieved at any $t \in [0, t_f]$

Comment: Unless $V'(t) > 0$, h=which I guess I can make that assumption.